# Quick way of checking for a condition while iterating the rows

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a dataframe of the below nature:

```
START             END               SHOP             ACTION
2016-01-07        2016-01-10        ABC              B
2016-01-10        2016-02-07        ABC              B
2016-04-07        2016-05-07        ABC              B
2016-05-15        2016-05-18        ABC              S
2016-10-07        2016-10-07        ABC              B
2016-11-07        2016-11-07        ABC              B
2016-01-15        2016-01-22        DEF              S
2016-05-22        2016-11-07        DEF              S
2016-11-07        2016-12-07        DEF              S
2016-01-04        2016-02-04        XYZ              B
2016-09-07        2016-10-26        XYZ              T
2016-10-25        2016-10-30        XYZ              B
```

I would like to create a new column such that for a given SHOP, it checks to see if there exists a start date (in future) that matches the end date (current date) and also matches the ACTION value.

So the Dataframe can look like

```
START             END               SHOP             ACTION   CHECK
2016-01-07        2016-01-10        ABC              B        1
2016-01-10        2016-02-07        ABC              B        0
2016-04-07        2016-05-07        ABC              B        0
2016-05-15        2016-05-18        ABC              S        0
2016-10-07        2016-10-07        ABC              B        0
2016-11-07        2016-11-07        ABC              B        0
2016-01-15        2016-01-22        DEF              S        0
2016-05-22        2016-11-07        DEF              S        1
2016-11-07        2016-12-07        DEF              S        0
2016-01-04        2016-02-04        XYZ              B        0
2016-09-07        2016-10-26        XYZ              T        0
2016-10-25        2016-10-30        XYZ              B        0
```

Comment: use `lamda functions`.

Comment: Can you please provide an example ?

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you -

```
df.merge(df.drop('END', axis=1).rename(index=str, columns = {'START':'END'}).assign(check=1), on=['END', 'SHOP', 'ACTION'], how='left').fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could do the thing you want by iterating over the dataframe, you also can accomplish the task with a groupby and join, like this:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.groupby("ACTION").apply(
    lambda x : pd.merge(
        left = x, right = x, how = "left", left_on = "END", right_on = "START", suffixes = ('', "_y")
    )
)
df["CHECK"] = df.index_y.notnull().astype(int)
df = df[["index", "START", "END", "SHOP", 'ACTION', "CHECK"]]
df = df.set_index("index")
```

If your table is too big, you can optimise the code above to be more "inplace"-like.